# Buidlbot Tutorial: URL for runtests under Waterfall view doesn't show?

Tags: python, buildbot

Doing [this tutorial](https://docs.buildbot.net/current/tutorial/firstrun.html), the URL for `runtests` in the Waterfall view does not appear. The worker is connected (confirmed by logs of both master and worker). Why doesn't `runtests` show under the Waterfall view?

I've tried the 2 ways that was shown in the tutorial in python's buildbot. (The first way is via the virtualenv and the second way is via the docker.) The link for the this is found [here](https://docs.buildbot.net/current/tutorial/firstrun.html#goal).

Both are supposed to show a URL (the tilted blue text) in waterfall view as seen in this image:

[image]

But both ways I tried only show a blank white screen. I ran the virtualenv way in both Linux Mint Serena and Ubuntu 16.04. I ran the docker way only in Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to Menu Builds -> Builders, click runtests and then you can see a "force" button on the top right hand corner. Click that button (before that make sure your worker is attached) and then you can see runtests in the waterfall view.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7OXr.png

Comment: Thank you, this made it work.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But it did not work for me. I have restarted my worker a few times and the logs all say it is connected. I see `runtests` in the builders list but only sometimes. I have to click back and forth between the options and only then does it appear. When I do click on `runtests` it takes me to Builderrequests page but there is no Force button. I looked for a scrollbar at the bottom and there is none. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Is it because I'm using `python3`?